# error in converting json to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
for i in products.iter():
    print i
```

This is the code I run and the output is as follows:

```
localhost:desktop siddharth$ python reader.py 
{u'sem3_id': u'1IngGhlIpoOGYCiMaEASSQ', u'cat_id': u'12151', u'updated_at': 1379589873, u'height': u'213.36', u'offers_total': 13, u'category': u'Inkjet Printers', u'price_currency': u'USD', u'sem3_help': u'To view image links for this product, please upgrade your plan.', u'width': u'281.94', u'sitedetails': [{u'sku': u'B00005AL05', u'latestoffers': [{u'price': u'366.99', u'shipping': u'19.98', u'seller': u'Buy4Less Now!', u'currency': u'USD', u'lastrecorded_at': 1379589800, u'firstrecorded_at': 1377106600, u'id': u'1BA5umTG80Gkg0oi40kiOu', u'condition': u'New'}, {u'price': u'379.96', u'shipping': u'12.49', u'seller': u'Battle Distribution, LLC', u'currency': u'USD', u'lastrecorded_at': 1379589800, u'firstrecorded_at': 1374975300, u'id': u'05cPhKOvouWkGc08sKaseq', u'condition': u'New'}, {u'price': u'99.99', u'shipping': u'12.49', u'seller': u'clabro', u'currency': u'USD', u'lastrecorded_at': 1379589800, u'firstrecorded_at': 1365164600, u'id': u'7aUtWYQlLkGuygGeWOgKWu', u'condition': u'Used - Very Good'}], u'name': u'amazon.com', u'url': u'http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00005AL05', u'offers_count': 13, u'recentoffers_count': 5}], u'price': u'366.99', u'gtins': [u'00033584113910'], u'ean': u'0033584113910', u'mpn': u'C408011', u'brand': u'Epson', u'geo': [u'usa'], u'manufacturer': u'Epson', u'name': u'Epson Stylus Photo 785EPX Inkjet Printer', u'created_at': 1347483414, u'upc': u'033584113910', u'length': u'264.16', u'model': u'C408011'}
```

How do i make this become a python dict?

I tried making a list comprehension from the iterator used above and then doing json.loads(listcomprehension) but this gives me errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start the list with a `[`, okay, but then you end it with a `)`. Change it to a `]`. `()` are for tuples.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[{"name":"same"}]')
[{u'name': u'same'}]
```

Comment: @garciaj Heh, don't worry, we all have that moment

Comment: hey haidro, how do you differentiate between a json string and a python dictionary?

Comment: @garciaj One's a string, one's a dictionary ;). `type(data)` will tell you which is which.

Comment: haidro ive edited the question could you please take a look at it

Comment: @garciaj What you have looks like a dictionary to me. is that the result of printing something? I'll need to see your code

Comment: https://www.semantics3.com/quickstart

in that link, ctrl find python and youll see the code i entered and what was printed :)

Comment: @garciaj I don't know what `semantics3` is, but you probably have a string there. After the print statement, do `print type(results)` to check

Comment: thats alright, looks like it already is a dictionary, last question, do u know how i can print every key:value on a different line for the output ive given above?

Comment: @garciaj `for k, v in json.loads('[{"name":"same"}]')[0].items(): print k, v`